# Setting a button in html

Tags: html, authentication, hyperlink, href

How do I set up a link button in html?

I want to set a button from the homepage so that user may be viewed by a log in screen. I have two index.html files, one for the homepage, and one for the login screen. How do I set it so when users click on log in they will be presented with the login screen.

I tried `<li><a href="login/index" class="button big special">Sign Up/lOG IN</a></li>`.

My goal was to use href= location of index.html.

When I click the link it takes me to an error page. The top link would be the address to the index file that has the login html.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have `.html` on your url. Try:

```
<li><a href="login/index.html" class="button big special">Sign Up/lOG IN</a></li>
```

Also, you are using a relative link, so the position of the file where you have this link is important. Right now it will look one directory up for a file named index.html. If the file with the link is `foo.html` make sure in the same folder you have a folder named `login` that has a file named `index.html`.

Comment: Glad to help! If this fully resolved your question, please mark it answered by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: It did :) but its telling me to wait five minutes before I do